# Hide layer on .click() in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with GoogleMaps and Bootstrap API.

[image]
What I want to do is add a button that when clicked hides a given the layer and displays a new one, I have been trying it with jQuery, but the problem is I can't hide the layer from the button .click() event.

```
//Javascript #indicacionmapa confirmation button
infowindow.setContent('<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-large" id="btnconfirmaubica"> Esta es la ubicación &#x2713; </a>');

//Jquery 
$(document).load(function() {
    $("#btnconfirmaubica").click(function () {
        $("#segundopaso").slideUp("slow");
        $("#primerpaso").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

I hope you can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change:

```
$(document).load(function() {
```

with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

also for dynamically generated elements you should delegate the event, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '#btnconfirmaubica', function() {
        $("#segundopaso").slideUp("slow");
        $("#primerpaso").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```